# Converting a Chrome extension into an Opera Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, manifest, enyo, opera-extension

I have a number of Chrome extensions that I'd like to convert to Opera extensions. I understand that from Opera 15 they both use the same Chromium architecture for extensions, but I can't even get the Opera manifest to be recognized.

My Chrome manifest looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "How Do You Do This In SAS?",
  "description": "How Do You Do This in SAS? is a free introduction to a series of eBooks about SAS software programming.",
  "version": "2.1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon16x16.png",
    "128": "icon128x128.png"},
  "app": {
    "launch": {
      "local_path": "index.html"
    }
  }
}
```

My index.html file contains the app data, and ends in:

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="source/load.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The load.js file contains:

```
new howsas00c().renderInto(document.body);
```

The howsas00c.js script uses the Enyo 1.0 framework, which is loaded in index.html.

So where do I start in fixing the manifest?

- I've added a 48x48 icon.
- I think the Opera manifest does not recognize the following:

> ```
> "app": {
>     "launch": {
>       "local_path": "index.html"
>     }
>   }
> ```

But what do I replace it with?................Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're right. The problem is the code starting with the "app". You actually prepared Chrome app not extension and Opera doesn't support apps yet. You should rewrite it to the extension rather (if it make sense for your application). See that document to get the difference: https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/articles/apps_vs_extensions

Comment: Looks like I'll have to wait for Opera to catch up with Chrome. My "extension" is implemented as an app, and is not an extension according to this article.  :-(